# Visual Studio 2010 Version Control and Bug Tracking capabilities

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, perforce

We are considering purchasing Perforce and OnTime for SCM and Bug Tracking respectively when discovered that with Visual Studio 2010 we'll get both Source Control & Bug Tracking integrated into it and **for free** (if you are a MSDN subscriber).

More in general, does it still worth to invest in these standalone and expensive tools? What are the benefits compared to what Visual Studio 2010 Team System has to offer?

I found this document but still refers to VS2008: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/comparisons/perforce_mstfs.pdf

Thanks,

Alberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the Team Foundation Server (TFS) Client Access Licence (CAL) each use will need at least MSDN-Professional (if I recall correctly). Other users will still need a separate CAL.

TFS does include both version control and work item tracking (and bugs are one kind of work item).

There are a number of reasons to prefer PerForce (or any other alternate ALM suite), includingL

- It does something you *need* that TFS doesn't. (Note "need", you might like it, but will you really use that feature having paid for it).
- You need to work with tools or people that use PerForce.

The starting point for TFS documentation is:

- Product Overview and more marketing/sales/overview information: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/products/2010/default.mspx#overview
- MSDN Documentation (details of usage, administration, customisation, ...): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fda2bad5(VS.100).aspx

With the VS2010 Release Candidate about to be freely available (tomorrow) why not give it a try. For some scale (evaluation use) it will run on a fairly low powered VM.

Comment: Do you mean that with a team of 5 programmers the MSDN Pro subscription we pay does not cover all the programmers?
We evaluated some SCM tools but you need often to leave VStudio and use the SCM client app, this is not comfortable at all... Already downloading the VS2010 TFS RC, thanks!

Comment: @devdept: Each developer who has an MSDN Pro (or better) is licensed to use TFS. (NB. One MSDN subscription is for one person, they can't be shared by two or more people.). By "other users" I meant roles like business analysts and project managers (who may well be entering/updating work items).

Comment: @Richard: WOW therefore we need a CAL license for each developer connecting to TFS, this is not for free as we thought. Thanks.

Comment: @devdept: And licences for *all* the other software they are using under MSDN. One MSDN Subscription ==> One Use. With MSDN, volume licensing is cheaper (even for a single subscription).

Comment: This is now a whitepaper on VS & TFS 2010 licensing: http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2009/10/20/tfs-2010-server-licensing-it-s-included-in-msdn-subscriptions.aspx

Comment: @Richard: Even this paper is not so clear for me, if our subscription to VS2010 Pro with MSDN includes TFS can 5 programmers work with it without purchasing anything else? Thanks.

Comment: @devdept: With 2010, each MSDN >=Pro includes a CAL for the subscriber. So 5 MSDN Pro subscriptions will licence the five subscribers to all use TFS.